# Throw exception in superclass does not work

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm using javascript with the following classes:

```
class A {
  constructor(config) {
    if (_.isEmpty(config) || !_.isObject(config)) {
      throw new Error('config cannot be null');
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
  }
}
```

I'm running the following test:

```
describe('B', function () {
    it('Should throw an error if instantiated without a config.', function () {
      expect(function () {
        const cs = new B(null);
      }).to.throw();
    });
  });
```

The problem is that the exception is not thrown,

If I do not extend class A and throw the exception in B then the test pass

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is weird, are you sure you are extending that same class A and not an other one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the problem was in the beforeEach function setting the config to something different than null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's an inheritance problem.  I ran this in the node.js REPL and it throws the expected error:

```
> class A {
... constructor(config) {
..... if (config == null) {
....... throw new Error('config cannot be null');
....... }
..... }
... }
undefined
> class B extends A {
... constructor(config) {
..... super(config);
..... }
... }
undefined
> new B(null);
Error: config cannot be null
    at new A (repl:4:7)
    at new B (repl:3:1)
>
```

The problem is likely not your use of inheritance.  Perhaps there is an issue with your lodash checks, browser, or a transpilation issue with Babel.  Or perhaps `A` and `B` are not what you think they are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the problem was in the beforeEach function setting the config to something different than null.